# LINQ To SQL Eager Loading with 1 to many and many to many Relation ships

Tags: linq-to-sql, eager-loading

I am new to using Linq to SQL and I have an issue

This is part of my model:

- Visit > VisitProduct < Product
- Visit > VisitSample < Product
- Visit > VisitStatus

I want to eager load the visit entity with all related entities,But It gives me an "InvalidCastexception". ,I use this code:

```
using (TeamsExcellenceDataContext context = new TeamsExcellenceDataContext())


{


            DataLoadOptions lo = new DataLoadOptions();
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
            lo.LoadWith<Visit>(v => v.Visitstatus);
            lo.LoadWith<Visit>(v => v.VisitProducts);
            lo.LoadWith<Visit>(v => v.VisitSamples);

            context.LoadOptions = lo;
            var temp = (from v in context.Visits
                   where v.VisitID == visitID
                   select v).Single();
            Visit v = temp;
        }
```

The generated SQL statement is split into 2 parts (**I don't know why this occur?**):

```
SELECT [t0].[VisitID], [t0].[StartDate], [t0].[EndDate], [t0].[TypeID], [t0].[StatusID], [t0].[NextObjective], [t0].[CpFeedback], [t0].[Feedback], [t0].[AccID], [t0].[CustMPID], [t0].[AccTreeID], [t0].[RepPermitDays], [t0].[ModeTypeID], [t0].[Recurrence], [t0].[RecurrenceParentKey], [t0].[CDate], [t2].[VisitID] AS [VisitID2], [t2].[ProductID], [t2].[VisitProductTurn], [t2].[CDate] AS [CDate2], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[VisitProducts] AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[VisitID] = [t0].[VisitID]
    ) AS [value], [t1].[VisitStatusID], [t1].[VisitStatusName], [t1].[VisitStatusMarker], [t1].[CDate] AS [CDate3]
FROM [dbo].[Visits] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Visitstatus] AS [t1] ON [t1].[VisitStatusID] = [t0].[StatusID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitProducts] AS [t2] ON [t2].[VisitID] = [t0].[VisitID]
WHERE [t0].[VisitID] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[VisitID], [t1].[VisitStatusID], [t2].[ProductID]
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [411]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT [t0].[VisiteID], [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[SampleQuantity], [t0].[CDate]
FROM [dbo].[VisitSamples] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[VisiteID] = @x1
-- @x1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [411]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1/
```

The exception doesn't not occur if I omit this line:

```
lo.LoadWith<Visit>(v => v.Visitstatus);
```

OR any of these lines

```
lo.LoadWith<Visit>(v => v.VisitSamples);
lo.LoadWith<Visit>(v => v.VisitProducts);
```

What I am doing wrong or how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the exception InvalidCastexception is thrown cause the primary key for the table Visitstatus is of type tinyint and apparently Linq To SQl has a problem with this DB data type so I changed the tinyint type to int and It works !!!

So this raises A question here what if I am not allowed to change the Data Base Design or it is crucial that I use the Data Base Type tinyInt Is there any work around ?

Comment: Then you should use byte as type in your model instead of int. TinyInt translates to byte.